# Pass selected value of Select Option as parameter in ahref

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have ahref :

```
<a href="@Url.Action("downloadDocument", "NewService", new { serviceId = item.ServiceId })" id="download"  target="_blank">Download</a>
```

And there is one Select Option on the same page :

```
<select class="required" data-val="true" id="DownloadValuesId" name="DownloadValuesId">
<option value="">option1</option>
<option value="2">option2</option>
<option value="3">option3</option>
<option value="4">option4</option>
<option value="5">option5</option>
</select>
```

How can I send the selected value as parameter in controller function called from ahref?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want when select any value from dropdown, get any action, try this:

HTML:

```
<select onchange = "redirect(this.value)" class="required" data-val="true" id="DownloadValuesId" name="DownloadValuesId">
<option value="">option1</option>
<option value="2">option2</option>
<option value="3">option3</option>
<option value="4">option4</option>
<option value="5">option5</option>
</select>
```

And javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function redirect(dropDownValue) {
          window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")/' + '?id=' + dropDownValue;
       }
</script>
```

**Edit:**

To send value with button use `onclick="AnyFunction()"` and take any **hidden** element. Firstly, give dropdown value to that hidden element, then send it to action with onclick:

```
<a id="download" onclick="SendValue()" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

And js:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function redirect(dropDownValue) {
           document.getElementById('hiddenElement').value = dropDownValue;
       }

      function SendValue() {
           window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")/' + '?id=' + document.getElementById('hiddenElement').value;
       }
   </script>
```

You also can do this using jquery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", //or GET
  url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")",
  data: "{ id : 'anyValue', serviceId : 'Any value'  }",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    //do something
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This is useful. But I want to do this on button click. i.e on button click I have to get selected value and send it to controller.

Comment: Is it also possible to send item.ServiceId as parameter in jquery function SendValue ? item being model.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can add many parameters to that url: For example, '?id=' + document.getElementById('hiddenElement').value + '&serviceId=' + '@item.ServiceId' + .....+... etc

Comment: I meant in the ahref from where jquery function is called.

Comment: I don't understand well.. You can send values to action with js and jquery.  Above i showed it with js.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34964/discussion-between-jhoon-bey-and-nitish)

Comment: window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")/' + '?id=' + document.getElementById('hiddenElement').value; I replaced my controller name here, but it is not calling the controller function.

Comment: That structure works for me in my code. Firstly check the hidden value has value or not. then try '/Controller/Action', if you use areas, add area name to url. Be sure that hidden element's id - 'hiddenElement' is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do that:

1. Use a form, put the select box in it and make your link submit the form. That way, the server will get the selected value.
2. Use Javascript to dynamically change the URL when the select box selection is changed.

I'd use the first option if possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with jquery, see below.

```
     <script>
       $('#DownloadValuesId').change(function(){
          var link = $('#download').attr('href');
          $('#download').attr('href') = link + "?id=" + $('#DownloadValuesId').val();
       });
     </script>

hope it helps.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try like this,

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){

  var Id = $("#DownloadValuesId").val(); // Dropdown Id

 window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")?DownloadValuesId=' + Id;

});
```